# Finite fields of even cardinality have characteristic $2$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Computer science studies-

as for now we have dealt with the set-theory and residue class rings with modular arithmetic, although we did not really define the connection between the two so rigorously

So I have to prove the following property for every $x \in \mathbb{F}$, whereas $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field with even cardinality:
$$ x+x = 0$$

As far as I considered it could be satisfied only with modular arithmetic, but apart of that I do not have a concrete approach..

Thank you for your help

Comment: You should use this fact: any finite field is of cardinal $p^n$ for $p$  a particular prime number, and is then a finite dimensional $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector space.

Comment: Please edit your question so that we know how much background you have.  There are many ways to prove this, but we need to know which of those ways are accessible to you.

Comment: @RobertShore   have just edited it

Comment: Do you know any group theory?  The easiest way to see this is probably to start by considering $F$ as an abelian group under addition.

Comment: @RobertShore yes I do. Wouldn't it be less general if one considers it an abelian group instead of a field? I mean, itll be a private case

Comment: @Ozk: no, it would be *more general*, hence applicable. Nevertheless all such fields can be constructed by formally joining a zero for an irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ to the base field $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, just like how $\Bbb C$ is obtained by formally joining $i$, a root of $x^2+1$ to $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's consider $F$ as an abelian group under addition.  Since $\vert F \vert$ is even, let $P$ be a $2$-Sylow subgroup of $F$.  Then $P$ is non-trivial and any non-zero element $z \in P$ has order $2^k$ for some $k \in \Bbb N$.  If $k \gt 1,$ let $y = 2^{k-1}z$.  If $k=1$, let $y = z$.  In either case, $F$ must have some element $y$ with order $2$; in other words, for that specific $y, y \neq 0 \text{ and } y+y=0$.

There's another way to see this.  Assume that $F$ has no element of additive order $2$.  Then you'd be able to partition $F$ by pairing up its non-zero elements,$\{x_n, -x_n\}$.  But $F$ has an odd number of non-zero elements, so that's not possible.  Thus, $F$ must have an element of order $2$.

Now choose an arbitrary $x \in F$ with $x \neq 0$.  Then $\frac xy$ exists and is nonzero and $x+x=y \frac xy+y \frac xy=(y+y) \frac xy=0$.

Alternatively, $0=y+y=1y+1y=(1+1)y \Rightarrow 1+1=0.$  Thus, for any $x \in F$ we have $x+x=1x+1x=(1+1)x=0x=0$.

Incidentally, this also proves that $\vert F \vert$ must be a power of $2$ because if an odd prime divided $\vert F \vert$, then $F$ would have to have an element of odd (additive) order, which we just proved can't happen.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on the fact, that $F$ should have an element $y$ with order 2 that satisfies $y+y=0=$ if its cardinality is even?

Comment: @Ozk I've edited to elaborate.

Comment: we haven't done Sylow groups and supgroups yet

Comment: @Ozk I've revised again to add a proof that doesn't use Sylow subgroups.